# Delegate implementation in between viewcontrollers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have 2 view controllers `VCA` and `VCB`.
Moving from `VCA` to `VCB`, with somevalue, is working fine

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCB") as! VCB
vc.entity = somevalue
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

But for reverse, I want to call a method in `VCA` from `VCB` after uploading certain data from `VCB`. And after that  refresh textfields valuesin `VCA`. I could have resfreshing code in viewwillappear in `VCA` but due to some reason i am n ot doing that but trying to implement delegate.
I have written some code as:

**VCA:**

```
class ProfileEditViewController:UIViewControoler, MobileVerifyDelegate{
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let mobileVC = MobileVerificationViewController()
    mobileVC.delegate = self
}

//MARK: - Mobileverify Delegate method
func delegateMethod() {
    print("a")

}
}
```

**VCB:**

```
    protocol MobileVerifyDelegate{
    func delegateMethod()
}


class MobileVerificationViewController: UIViewController{
 var delegate: MobileVerifyDelegate! = nil
func certainFunction(){
     //aftersuccessful upload
     self?.delegate.delegateMethod()// code crashes
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad` of VCA you've created `mobileVC` but when you transition to VCB, you're creating a new instance of VCB named `vc`. `mobileVC` is unused the way it is. You have a few options:

make `mobileVC` a class property or set the delegate while creating `vc`.

The latter would be:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCB") as! VCB
vc.entity = someValue
vc.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

On a sidenote, make your delegate confirming the class protocol so you can set the delegate as weak.

```
protocol MobileVerifyDelegate: class {
    func delegateMethod()
}

class MobileVerificationViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: MobileVerifyDelegate?

    func certainFunction() {

        // After successful upload
        delegate?.delegateMethod()
    }
}
```

Notice that when you set an implicitly unwrapped property, it is already `nil`. So it's redundant to set it as `nil` again.

```
var delegate: MobileVerifyDelegate! = nil // "= nil" is not needed
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your case is but the easiest solution would be to move the delegate method and delegate to `VCB`. If for whatever reason you `VCA` has to be the delegate class then you need to create an instance of it or pass it to `VCB`.

```
//Set delegate when you push to the new controller in VCA
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCB") as! VCB
vc.entity = somevalue
vc.delegate = self //Sets VCA as VCB's Delegate        
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

//Inside VCB
self.delegateMethod() //Now you can call any delegate protocol methods from VCA
```

Comment: In your example, you're creating a new instance of `VCA` though. When calling the delegate method, it will pass it to the new `VCA` which in most cases is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I realized as I was typing this wasn't the best way and updated my answer to show how you would set it the `VC` that pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, `Delegate` is the way that you need to get what you aspected. there is some problem in completely implementing delegate in swift. here  i provide link which fully guide you how to implemented delegate in swift.

[Delegate In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710381/uiview-class-for-drop-down-list-with-uibuttons-delegate-protocol-issue/29713992#29713992)

As you said that, App crash on calling delegate. that means, you method is not available in `VCA` or delegate has not reference of `VCA`. kindly check this two condition.

Thanks

Comment: @Team Srijana, let me know if you need any help